# How to use mysql Joins in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and i am using expressjs,And i am using "mysql database", Right now i want to concat and use join (with paramerized) query , How can i do this ? I have following query and i want to write this query in express js (paramerized),How can i do this ?

```
SELECT `sd`.`service_id`, `sd`.`gender_type_id`, `sd`.`price`, `s`.`service_name`, concat('http://localhost/project/services/', s.image) as image, `s`.`time`
FROM `services_detail` `sd`
JOIN `services` `s` ON `sd`.`service_id`=`s`.`id`
WHERE `sd`.`id` = 13896
```